# Can admin role auto login a Cognoto user without a password?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have a serverless function in AWS lambda that receives an oauth callback from an external authorizer. This happens when an external app wants to send a user into my app.

In here I do the handshake with the external authorizer after which point I can say I have authenticated with that external authorizor.

After this I want to translate this authenticated user to an internal Cognito User in my app (because my react app and my backend work with Cognito userTokens and temporary aws IAM credentials).

So at this point its easy enough for me to create a Cognito user (triggering an email with a generated username/password) and redirecting the user to the login form of my app. Then they can log into my app.

While it is good that the user now has a direct way of getting into my app (through my login form rather than the external app), the requirement I have is that the user should not have to re-login if they actually do come from that external app.

With this in mind I have a simple question: Is it possible for me to auto login a user programmatically at the backend (without knowing their password) in order to get a Cognito token (..getIdToken().getJwtToken()) that I can send to my frontend. If my front end has that token then it has everything it needs to work without explicit login via the form

Answer (score 0):

> So at this point its easy enough for me to create a Cognito user (triggering an email with a generated username/password)

You mean you validate the info received in your lambda (JWT token etc.) or implicitly trust the info (not recommended) and use this to create a Cognito user. Is this correct? If so, you must have provided a temporary password while creating the user. You can use use this to login directly using AdminInitiateAuth command. If your flow is different, please specify.